# How to remove a line with space using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I want to remove a line which begins with `<Field name="LastDate"` in a xml file.

The space seems to be creating issues here `sed -i /^<Field name="LastDate"/d test.xml`. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the script *(single quotes as the text already contains double quotes)*:

```
$ sed -i '/^<Field name="LastDate"/d' test.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it.